# BASH : How to transfer ouput of a html page into a txt file

Tags: html, bash, wget

I have to transfer output of HTML page on any browser to a txt file using Bash script.
The HTML file will be in same folder as of txt file.

I tried to use wget but that only work with links.
so I opened the html file first on browser then copied link from there but that doesnt seem to work.

The command written was:
wget "file:///tmp/mozilla_vishal0/vishal.html" > fil.txt

That gave me error like this:
file:///tmp/mozilla_vishal0/vishal.html: Unsupported scheme ‘file’.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘*output of HTML page*’?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cp` to copy local files.

```
cp /tmp/mozilla_vishal0/vishal.html fil.txt
```

Comment: By Output of html page I mean the text which is visible to us on opening the html file on browser. Like wiki text which is output of wiki source code.

Comment: @VishalVerma — That is not what `wget "file:///tmp/mozilla_vishal0/vishal.html" > fil.txt` would do if you used a URL it supported.

Comment: OK so I want a solution for that thing.

Comment: Look at the duplicate then.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
curl -L https://google.com > output.txt
```

which mean using curl to get https://google.com with follow redirect option.
then save output to output.txt instead of [stdout](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/stdout.htm)

Comment: I only want data which is visible to us on browser (not source code) . Also the html file is local (IE. On your PC).